# Android Media Player stops after second song

Tags: java, android

I am making a music player app and I have a problem. After playing a song next song starts playing but when the second song is done playing it freezes and does nothing. It used to say on a log that the media player went away with unhandled events but I've found another way to handle it with Player.this.runOnUiThread and now it doesn't say that but still doesn't work. There is the code:

```
String sname;
public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "song_name";
static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
int position;
ArrayList<File> mySongs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();

    mySongs = (ArrayList) bundle.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
    String songName = i.getStringExtra("songName");
    position = bundle.getInt("pos", 0);
    txtsname.setSelected(true);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    sname = mySongs.get(position).getName();
    txtsname.setText(sname);

    setAlbumCover();

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
    mediaPlayer.start();

    Player.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           if(mediaPlayer != null){
            int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            seekMusic.setProgress(currentPosition);
           }
        }
    });

    seekMusic.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

    seekMusic.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    seekMusic.getThumb().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    seekMusic.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
        }
    });

    String endTime = evalTime(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    txtsstop.setText(endTime);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 500;

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String currTime = evalTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            seekMusic.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            txtsstart.setText(currTime);
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);

    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
            else{
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    });

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!shuffle){
                position = ((position + 1) % mySongs.size());

                playSong(position);
            }
            else {
                Random rand = new Random();

                position = rand.nextInt(mySongs.size());

                playSong(position);
            }
        }
    });

    previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position = ((position - 1 >= 0) ? position - 1 : mySongs.size() - 1);
            playSong(position);
        }
    });

    shuffleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!shuffle) {
                shuffle = true;
                loop = false;

                loopButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.button), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                shuffleButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.activeButton), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
            else {
                shuffle = false;
                loop = false;

                shuffleButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.button), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        }
    });

    loopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!loop) {
                loop = true;
                shuffle = false;

                shuffleButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.button), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                loopButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.activeButton), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
            else {
                loop = false;
                shuffle = false;

                loopButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.button), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        }
    });

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (loop) {
                playSong(position);
                loop = true;
            }
            else nextButton.performClick();
        }
    });
}
public String evalTime (int duration){
    String time = "";
    int min = duration / 1000 / 60;
    int sec = duration / 1000 % 60;

    time += min + ":";
    if(sec < 10){
        time += "0";
    }
    time += sec;

    return time;
}

public void playSong(int pos){
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;

    Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(pos).toString());

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
    sname = mySongs.get(pos).getName();
    txtsname.setText(sname);

    seekMusic.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    String endTime = evalTime(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    txtsstop.setText(endTime);

    mediaPlayer.start();

    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
    setAlbumCover();
}
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

after creating new instance of `MediaPlayer` (in your case using `MediaPlayer.create(`) you have to wait when it gets prepared, only then you may call `start()`

use [`mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)) and start playing when it fires

but at first get familiar with [`MediaPlayer` doc and state diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer). may be easier to use some lib, e.g. [`ExoPlayer`](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

besides that you should have two methods: for starting and destroying player. currently you are initiating player in `onCreate` in one way (simpler) and another similar piece of code is in `playSong` method. would be better to read `pos` from `Bundle` and call `playSong` straight inside `onCreate`

Comment: I made some changes to code as you said, made destroyMediaPlayer method which does stop reset release and set null, also deleted all lines from onCreate that created media player and now im calling playSong method in there and everywhere where was mediaPlayer.start() I added setOnPreparedListener and mediaPlayer.start() in it and app still works but theres still this problem that after playing first song the second song freezes on completion. The only way to play next song is to press next button

Comment: you are setting `setOnCompletionListener` only once in `onCreate`, but every song play is creating new `MediaPlayer` instance, thus needs new `setOnCompletionListener` call. just move this setter to `playSong`

Comment: Yesterday I've noticed that now with those changes when I play song and press back button to go back to the song list and play another song it starts playing it without stopping this last one so it plays multiple songs at once and I can't figure out why. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: that may happen if you (still) have this declaration: `static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;`. read about `static` keyword and avoid it as much as you can :) in here you may just remove this word. after this change checking `if(mediaPlayer != null)` in `onCreate` is rendudant, player will always be null. thats my first thought, but I don't see current code, would be better to open new question with updated code (and you can call me commenting in here with link to new question, but I don't guarantee that I will answer, but maybe someone do :) )

Comment: btw. you very should kill/release `MediaPlayer` in `onDestroy` so you may copy/move whole `if(mediaPlayer != null) {...}` from `onCreate`

Comment: at least: if you are considering my (or any other) answers valuable then use upvoting button, if answer is fixing your problem then use accepting answer checkmark, that motivates to further support ;)

Comment: The static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer declaration wasn't static anymore and doing mediaPlayer.pause() in onDestroy method helped however I would prefer to not stop the song while browsing through song list but after selecting another song just stop last start new. Can you give me any advice? About upvoting I just created account on stack last week and to upvote i need 15rep (11 right now) and I wanted to just reply comment with thanks but I read somewhere that you should avoid writing comments like this so didn't write it however I appreciate all your help I will upvote when I can.

Comment: `static MediaPlayer` is in fact a memory leak, thats not a proper way. you should introduce some foreground [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services), which can play in background even when app is "homed"